# Unable to get response from server

Tags: ios, networking

Unable to hit the server through `iPhone` Simulator, But able to hit the same API through a browser (with proxies enabled in network settings).

There is no trusted certificate.

Error Log

> nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: NSURLErrorDomain: -1003
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed 
>   The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be "domain name"...

TIC SSL Trust Error

Comment: Try to set NSAppTransportSecurity to True in your app's info.plist file.

Comment: Hi Manish, I already set NSAppTransportSecurity to true in info Plist file but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding at the end of your Appdelegate class after @end,

**Objective-C**

```
@implementation NSURLRequest(ATS)
+ (BOOL)allowsAnyHTTPSCertificateForHost:(NSString *)host {
    return YES;
}
@end
```

**Swift**

```
extension URLRequest {
    static func allowsAnyHTTPSCertificate(forHost host: String?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Manish, can you suggest me how to set this property in swift for any URLRequest.